Django 400 only post request allowed
I am testing two methods for posting a file. I have a frontend in React.js and backend in Django. I keep on receiving method get not allowed when attempting to post a file. Why can't the post method work as well? I have the following code for my front end.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext';

function FileUpload({ setUploads = () => {} }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
  const { authTokens, logoutUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const accessToken = String(authTokens.access);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetch(`http://server:8000/api/upload/${id}/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        },
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  setPhoto(data.photo.name);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error fetching photo:', error);
});
}
}, [id, accessToken]);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', photo);

try {
let response;
if (id) {
  response = await fetch(`http//server:8000/api/upload/${id}/`, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
    body: formData,
  });
} else {
server:8000/api/files/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
},
body: formData,
});
}

const data = await response.json();
if (!response.ok) {
throw new Error(data.message || 'Something went wrong');
}

if (id) {
setUploads((prevUploads) =>
prevUploads.map((upload) => (upload.id === data.id ? data : upload))
);
alert('File updated successfully!');
navigate(`/upload/${data.id}`);
} else {
setUploads((prevUploads) => [data, ...prevUploads]);
alert('Upload created successfully!');
navigate('/');
}

setPhoto(null);
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error uploading photo:', error);
}
};
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="photo" className="block font-medium text-gray-700">
            Photo/File
          </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            name="photo"
            id="photo"
            onChange={(e) => setPhoto(e.target.files[0])}
            className="border border-gray-400 rounded w-full px-3 py-2 mt-1 text-gray-900"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-6">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-medium py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2"
          >
            {id ? 'Update Upload' : 'Create Upload'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileUpload;

For my backend views:

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from base.serializer import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        token['username'] = user.username

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        'api/file/'
        '/api/token/',
        '/api/register/',
        '/api/token/refresh/',
        '/api/prediction/'
        'api/uploads/',
        'api/upload/<int:pk>/',
        'api/upload/<int:pk>/update/',
        'api/upload/<int:pk>/delete/',
        'api/upload/myuploads/',
        'api/upload/create/',
        'api/profile/',
        'api/profile/update/',
        'api/users/<int:pk>/upload',    ]
    return Response(routes)
#############################ADD THIS############################################
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUploads(request):
    public_upload = Upload.objects.filter(is_public=True).order_by('-updated')[:10]
    user_upload = request.user.uploads.all().order_by('-updated')[:10]
    uploads = public_upload | user_upload
    serializer = uploadsSerializer(uploads, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


#api/notes/<int:pk>
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUpload(request, pk):
    upload = request.user.upload.get(id=pk)
    serializer = uploadSerializer(upload, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


#api/notes/<int:pk>/update
@api_view(['PATCH'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateUpload(request, pk):
    upload = request.user.upload.get(id=pk)
    serializer = uploadSerializer(instance=upload, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)



#api/notes/<int:pk>/delete
@api_view(['DELETE'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def deleteUpload(request, pk):
    upload = request.user.upload.get(id=pk)
    upload.delete()
    return Response('File was deleted')

#api/notes/create
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createUpload(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data
    upload = Upload.objects.create(
           user=user,
        photo=data['photo']
    )
    serializer = upploadSerializer(upload, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

##################################
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
   # @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    #parser_classe = [FileUploadParser]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

      file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file_serializer.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
#api/notes/user/<int:pk>/mynotes
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUserUpload(request, pk):
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    uploads = Upload.objects.filter(user=user)
    serializer = uploadSerializer(uploads, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
##################################################################################
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


I tried rewriting the frontend fetch request.
I tried to change the white list cors settings to false.
